# Flex Box Fill Space of Unknown Height with Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am using Bootstrap 4 and need to frame in 3 different boxes. The frame will have 2 columns. One box in the left column and 2 boxes in the second column. The box in the first column is a responsive image that determines the height of the frame. The height will not be known.

The top box in the second column will also be responsive and take priority of height in the column. The third box (bottom-right) will contain content that can be scrolled, but it should fill the remaining height in the second column.

[See picture of desired result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znGF0.png)

So far, I've only been able to do this by setting a height. And, I don't want to do that. Any ideas?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container pt-3">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="bg-white p-3">
    <div class="row">
     
     <div class="col-sm-8 pr-sm-1 pb-sm-2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" class="img-fluid">
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-sm-4 pl-sm-1">
      <div class="mb-2">
       <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="bg-secondary">
       <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
          
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see someone else coming up with another answer, but the short answer is that, *no, you can't*. You can't have the desired effect without actually knowing the height occupied by the left image.

**BUT**, if you make a couple of assumptions, you can safely predict it:

- **Assumption 1**: The images you use are a of the same aspect ratio, e.g. 16/9 (like the ones you used in the example)
- **Assumption 2**: Your 3-boxes structure always lives inside a `.container` (like in your example)

Since Bootstrap uses fixed sizes for `.container` class for different breakpoints, you can safely come up with a value for the height of the third box, e.g:

```
.list-group {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .list-group {
    height: 120px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .list-group {
    height: 165px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .list-group {
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

You can see the result [here](https://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/rzvzyo). I have used Bootstrap's Flex utility to position the boxes. You will have to complete the remaining breakpoints.